# хранение и использование данных о действии клиентов [mysql]

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация

Привет всем! Нужно хранить в бд какие видео смотрел пользователь и на какую секунду прекратил смотреть( в секундах )

вот что в голову приходит

1. сделать одну таблицу вроде

```
________________________________________________________________________________
| [ user_id ]  |   [ video_id_last_sec ( тип данных text) ]
================================================================================
| 102          |   589(id видео)>56(последняя секунда просмотра)|(разделитель)254(id другого видео)>89(поледняя секунда другого видео)
________________________________________________________________________________
| 56           |   189>286|785>14|652>87
================================================================================
```

далее, когда начнёт смотреть видео который не досмотрел,получать video_id_last_sec по id пользователя, обрабатывать и вывести то что нужно. но думаю это будет проблемно, потому что последную секунду просмотра нужно обновлять каждые 20 секунд и если клиент смотрел н.п 1000 видео то будет сложно и медленно каждые 20 секунд получать  video_id_last_sec  обрабатывать и записывать заного.

2. или можно во время регистрации пользователя создать табоицу для него. что-то вроде

имя таблицы - id пользователя
сама таблица

```
_____________________________
[ video_id ]  |  [ last_sec]
=============================
589           |  56
254           |  89
=============================
```

но в этом случае при н.п 100000 пользователей соберётся 100000 таблиц, а в интернете прочитал что это может замедлить работу

3. сохранить данные в куки. но в этом случае с других устойств не будет доступа.

есть какие нибудь идеи?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте таблицу: ид юзера, ид видео, последняя секунда просмотра. И получайте из нее данные по конкретному юзеру + видео. А это поле (video_id_last_sec) уберите.

Comment: добавление такого количества таблиц не замедлит работу, оно сделает ее в принципе невозможной. MySQL не хватит количества открытых файлов. Делайте как сказал @Visman та же структура что вы ходели для личной таблицы пользователя, только в нее добавляется еще user_id. Дальше надо думать над различными оптимизациями, так часто писать в БД не стоит. для начала максимально отработать все на стороне клиента, если удастся отследить все виды прекращения проигрывания видео (включая закрытие окна) то сообщайте на сервер например раз минуту + по прекращению просмотра.

Comment: На самом сервере может стоит поднять какой то кеш вроде memcached из которого данные в БД сбрасывать вообще редко, скажем раз в 10 мин или когда потребуется очистить кеш.

Comment: Спосибо всем. Hешил секунды просмотра хранить в куки и когда пользователь нв сайте каждые 10 минут отправить данные на сервер и записать в одну общую таблицу как сказал @Visman